# What is the recourse for defamation?

Tags: united-states, defamation

I came across this question today https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/i-was-mistakenly-identified-as-a-criminal-and-this-has-caused-rumors-how-can-i and I think OP is taking the issue way too lightly.

What kind of recourse can OP pursue to swiftly clear their name? Do they have a strong case for egregious defamation?

---

Full story below in case the IPS link goes bad in the future:

> A while ago, I was at a popular, busy local nightclub (this is in the Unites States) and ran into a friend of a friend. Let's call her Anne. After a bit of conversation with Anne, and mutual name-dropping of our overlapping social networks, a bouncer approached me and said that he was asked to escort me off the premises. I had no idea why, and the bouncer said he did not know either, only that I had to leave immediately. I know enough not to argue when the door staff have made up their mind, so I agreed to leave without complaint.
>
> I assumed it was because maybe I looked a little intoxicated-- I wasn't really, I had 2.5 drinks over 2 hours-- and thought nothing more of it.
>
> A week later, a different friend contacted me and informed me that I had been 86'd from the club because I am a "known sex offender." After I had been escorted out, the bouncer had told Anne this. Anne, by the way, volunteers as a rape counselor and is a strong and feminist advocate for social justice. Over the past week she had defriended me on social networks and starting contacting our mutual friends to inform them of this "fact" out of concern. Because I am defriended I cannot see what she is saying about me nor can I respond. I only heard about this from a friend of a friend of a friend.
>
> This is a clear case of mistaken identity. I hadn't been in that club in more than five years, so there was no way I was a person that would have been known to them. I have done a search of the local sex offenders registry and I am not in it. I have never been arrested, let alone indicted of a crime.
>
> I am obviously devastated by this and very depressed. I am not sure what to do about it. My friend suggested I go back to the club and confront the manager, but my feeling is that in a situation like that the manager has to side with their employees.
>
> I considered reaching out directly to Anne, but my gut tells me, given the situation, that she would interpret this as a form of intimidation and it would simply make things worse.
>
> What can I do to fix this situation? My goal is to quash the rumors and cleanse my reputation in my social circle.

Comment: I don't want to argue with someone in the answer's but this is not defimation.

Comment: @Putvi I would actually be highly curious to hear why this is not defamation. I am no legal expert by any stretch of the imagination so I would gladly upvote an answer that tells me why my notion is misguided. I assume there are some slight nuances in the definitions which I've read.

Comment: It's not defamation, because the bar could have thought they had reason to kick the person out. If I think you are a murderer and kick you out of something, but it turns out you aren't, I made a mistake. If I KNOW you are not one and go around saying you are to harm you that is defamation.

Comment: @Putvi I see. If not defamation charges then could you provide an answer for the correct course of action? Does OP have a legal route such as sending a cease and desist to Anne? Assuming of course that OP can prove that she is still spreading wrongful information?

Comment: No, not everything goes to court. I don't mean this in a rude way, but in this case you just have to talk to your friends and explain what happened and move on.

Comment: @Putvi No offense taken. I'm asking on behalf of the OP from the original question. It seems to have taken a tangible toll on their life. Knowing what options you don't have can be just as important as knowing what options you do have.

Comment: @Putvi And what about the used-to-be acquaintance who started spreading the story all over the friends of the person that had been evicted? Can you say it is definitely not defamation without actually knowing the content of those stories.

Comment: @VladimirF I think the silver lining is that Anne thinks she is spreading the truth and hasn't been informed otherwise so it would be near impossible to call it defamation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Truth based on hearsay. So, a cease and desist letter should probably come first. After that she definitely is informed. Also, I am not not a lawyer, the less a US one, but there should be a difference between saying "the bouncer said: a quote" and saying "he is a sex offender". And we do not know what actually happened.

Comment: @VladimirF Agreed and I mentioned cease and desist in an earlier comment but Putvi said "not everything goes to court" so I'm not sure if that means that the court would reject a cease and desist or that getting enough evidence to obtain a cease and desist will take too long or be impossible.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus a cease and desist is a letter. It never goes to court. It's a warning saying you will go to court.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus there is no legal issue here is what I am saying. This is a rumor that caused a disagreement between friends the same as kids do in school daily. Defamation in court enforceable sense is when someone makes up something and it hurts you professionally or in advancing in something significant, not something that causes your bar friends to get mad at you.

Comment: Would the situation be different if the bouncer (and Anne) had phrased it as *alleged* sex offender?

Comment: @Putvi Except it doesn't sound like this is some rumour that Anne is pushing; it's not an "I heard ...". It sounds like she's outright informing people that the poster is a sex offender, without even having verified this in any way. This is something that can seriously affect the poster's reputation, relationships, and potentially even job prospects.

Comment: She is saying it that way bc she heard it and believes it to be true.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "*Would the situation be different if the bouncer (and Anne) had phrased it as alleged sex offender?*" Maybe not. In [*Milkovich v. Lorain Journal Co.*, 497 U.S. 1, 19 (1990)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1990498497us11498), the SCOTUS admitted that, even when using prefixes of the sort "I think" or "in my opinion", those statements "*can cause as much damage to reputation as the statement [without that prefix]*".  A similar rationale would apply to "alleged". Scandalous terms of a statement are likelier to stick to people's mind than a "weakening" or blurry prefix.

Answer (score 7):

> *What kind of recourse can OP pursue to swiftly clear their name?*

The OP's "recourse" is to prove the truth - that he is not a convicted or accused  (by a prosecutor) sex offender - to those who defamed him, who are *presumably* the bar owner(s), who instructed the bouncer to remove the OP because he was a sex offender; and possibly the bouncer, who may have told Anne that the OP was a sex offender; and possibly others who later on social media said the OP is a sex offender, such as Anne herself.

The facts of who may be a sex offender and who may have falsely asserted someone is must be sorted out, and that's usually done by lawyers before a lawsuit (with a possible settlement from *"We're going to sue"* threat letter by the OP's lawyer); or in the discovery process of an actual lawsuit; or in court by a jury.

It's entirely up to the OP to take legal action, hopefully under the advice of a lawyer; and it's not a good idea for the OP to confront the bouncer, Anne or others and possibly complicate his own situation. As for anything happening "swiftly", that's another point entirely.

The OP could sue for damages to his reputation and/or to require the defamers to retract their statements, or for other compensations. Many personal injury lawyers give free initial consultations.

See [Defamation | Legal Information Institute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/defamation) for definitions and the laws regarding defamation, libel and slander (which can vary due to jurisdiction; in some areas, defamation is criminal as well as civil). Libel is published defamation, as in defaming someone in messages on social media; slander is spoken defamation, such as what the bar bouncer may have done.

> *Do they have a strong case for egregious defamation?*

The likelihood of "a strong case" is for the OP's legal counsel to determine; they will look at the evidence of defamatory statements, the likelihood of getting monetary damages from the bar and/or the individuals involved, and other factors.

Comment: You are misapplying the notion of *truth as absolute defense*. That is something that defendants --not plaintiffs-- typically plead *as an affirmative defense* in a defamation lawsuit. Also, proving negatives is oftentimes impossible. Instead, the point is to corner the defendant into "proving" the veracity of the defamatory statements the defendant made.

Comment: @IñakiViggers is correct.  "Truth as an absolute defense" in this case would describe Anne, at a defamation trial, proving that that the writer on [Interpersonal.SE] actually *was* a known sex offender.

Answer (score 7):

Scott seemingly has a viable claim of *defamation per se*. If the matter has caused him concrete losses (typically in the form of losing employment, business, or prospect thereof), he could also sue for *defamation per quod*.

The matter of defamation *per se* will require him to prove the defendant's mental state known in defamation law as *actual malice*. That term refers to defendant's knowledge --at the time of making the statements-- that the statements were false or defendant's reckless disregard of the truth or falsity of the defamatory falsehoods.

During the discovery stage of the judicial proceedings, Scott might be able to ascertain the source of the defamatory falsehoods. That will be crucial toward proving the defendants' role and mental state regarding the false accusations.

Being a mental state, actual malice is somewhat difficult to prove. Scott gives no information --and apparently has none-- about the alleged source of the bouncer's "knowledge". For instance, he might just have followed instructions from his employer, who in turn would be another defendant to the lawsuit.

As for Anne, her reckless disregard of the truth (and hence *actual malice*) might be easier to prove. She as "rape counselor" is expected to have undergone some training, and thus be aware --as all of us are-- that many accusations of sexual misconduct are false. Thus, she will have a harder time explaining why despite her alleged profile of "rape counselor" she rushed to spread the falsehoods.

> Because I am defriended I cannot see what she is saying about me nor can I respond.

Before she removes her posts, Scott should ask mutual friends to save copies or take screenshots of what she has been posting about him. That evidence is important even if Scott eventually subpoenaes the social networks where Anne is defaming Scott.

The statute of limitations for claims of defamation is one year --from the time of publication of a defamatory falsehood-- in most of the U.S. An exception is Tennessee, where it is only six months. Scott will be able to sue only for publications/statements being made less than a year (or six months, accordingly) ago. This is noteworthy because Scott begins his inquiry with "*A while ago*".

Some jurisdictions, such as Texas and Florida, require the plaintiff to demand a retraction from the would-be defendant. That request for retraction ought to happen prior to filing suit. Otherwise, his lawsuit would be easily dismissed in court. In other jurisdictions (example: [Michigan](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(wrlyrsx3zjyoc5bcnx0xbtdk))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-600-2911)) a request for retraction is a prerequisite only for purposes of punitive and exemplary damages.

Even if Scott's case is presided/obstructed by corrupt judges, of which there are plenty in the US, he will be able to obtain evidence that sets --or helps to set -- the record straight.

Comment: Isn't actual malice only the standard if OP is a public figure?  I thought for private citizens there was a lower burden on the plaintiff.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian The burden would be a bit less stringent for a private plaintiff, but he would still need to prove *actual malice* in order to be awarded more than *nominal damages* of $1. The rationale is that the public figure has easy access to the media so as to counter the defamatory falsehoods, whereas private plaintiffs have no such access. Thus, courts purport to compensate that disadvantage by lowering a little bit the standard of proof of *actual malice* in those cases.

Comment: @IñakiViggers defamation means you knowingly defamed someone. If the bar didn't know they were wrong this would not fit. SMH

Comment: @Putvi Your statement only summarizes the notion of *actual malice*. But absent a need to prove *actual malice*, negligence suffices for prevailing in a claim of defamation per quod. See MCL 600.2911(7) in the link I posted when mentioning Michigan. Whether or not the bar was negligent (or worse), that is something for the defamed plaintiff to ascertain during discovery.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Regarding the difference in standards of proof, see [*Seley-Radtke v. Hosmane*, 149 A.3d 573, 584 (2016)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inmdco20161122277): "*public figures usually enjoy significantly greater access to the channels of effective communication and hence have a more realistic opportunity to counteract false statements than private individuals normally enjoy. [...] As such, private individuals are more vulnerable to injury, and the [S]tate interest in protecting them is correspondingly greater.*" (quotation marks removed).

Comment: "The existence of both common law and First Amendment conditional privilege is a question of law, and the defendant has the burden of proof with respect to establishing the privilege"

Comment: Your link destroys your argument.

Comment: @Putvi You are making no sense. The First Amendment does not protect false statements of fact. And it is obvious that you are not reading carefully the links, or at least you would bother articulating how you think the link "destroys" my argument. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100438/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-putvi).

Comment: How is quoting from your own link making now sense?

Comment: Reckless disregard by a bouncer is not obvious. Reckless disregard by a rape counselor, blind Freddy would agree.

Comment: It is a shame that you detract from an otherwise good answer by continually contending that a large proportion of judges are corrupt.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I am not here to cater to judges and lawyers, but to give to the rest of the people an informed perspective of how the law is in theory *and* (or I should say, *versus*) in real life. I'm just not into the business of misleading people that the judicial system is "all a world of integrity".

Comment: My opinion is that you may be misleading people in the other direction based on your own unfortunate experiences. Or people may just mentally devalue your answers due to  gratuitous comments about judges that are not specifically relevant to their question.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I have also denounced other judges who have nothing to do with my unfortunate experiences. And my remark is relevant to the OP's question, since I highlight why judicial corruption alone should not dissuade the defamed person from  proceeding against the wrongdoers. Unlike your concern about people "mentally devaluing" my answers, I am fairly confident about the audience's ability to assess the contents of the answer altogether rather than cherry-picking for the sake of downvoting.

Comment: The definition of Demfimation Per Se is incorrect here.  Per Se means you do not need to prove that damages happened as the defamatory statements are so socially reprehensible that it becomes obvious.  Being guilty of a crime one was never convicted nor even charged with is a classic example, but so is a lie about having a disease or other non-criminal offense (i.e. holding unpopular political opinions).  Provided that the plaintiff was a private person at the time of the defamation, the actual malice standard is not applicable.

Comment: Or to better explain, Per Se defamation does not require any evidence of damages.  Actual Malice only applies if at the time the defamation occurred, the person was not publicly recognizable (typically it's only applicable to celebrities or politicians).  Certainly being banned from a club is enough in terms of damages.

Comment: @hszmv "*The definition of Demfimation Per Se is incorrect here*". My answer was not an attempt to define defamation per se at all. And your concepts of *defamation per se* and *actual malice* are quite flawed: Actual malice is not a "standard", but a mental state; private persons need to prove actual malice to overcome a defendant's qualified privilege or --in defamation per se-- to obtain recovery of more than nominal damages of $1; U.S. case law is clear that not all false accusations of crimes are defamatory per se, but only those of felonies and those which falsely impute moral turpitude.